# MySQL Min Max deduction

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table that used to store fuel issuing details for different vehicles as follows:

```
+----+------------+-----+---------------+-------------+
| id | vehicle_no | qty | meter_reading | date_issued |
+----+------------+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  1 |        366 |  50 |         10500 | 2019-09-01  |
|  2 |        366 |  50 |         11020 | 2019-09-02  |
|  3 |        367 |  25 |         25000 | 2019-09-03  |
|  4 |        366 |  50 |         11450 | 2019-09-04  |
|  5 |        368 |  50 |          6000 | 2019-09-05  |
+----+------------+-----+---------------+-------------+
```

02) Then I need to find no of Kilometers run against issued sum of fuel quantities.

03) I used the following query

```
select f1.vehicle_no, (select f1.meter_reading-f2.meter_reading)/sum(qty) from fuel f1) from fuel f2 group by vehicle_no
```

04) I want to get the desired output as follows :

As an example :

```
the meter reading of id=4 - meter reading of id=2 is 430 Kilometers 
the meter reading of id=4 - meter reading of id=1 is 950 Kilometers
the meter reading of id=2 - meter reading of id=1 is 520 Kilometers
```

But I did not get the expected result. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: i very much doubt that is the query which you are running as it should give a [parse error](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5TksFW2TdPP5McY88E7ALJ/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a self join:

```
select 
  f.id,
  ff.id,
  f.vehicle_no,
  f.date_issued,
  ff.date_issued,
  f.meter_reading - ff.meter_reading as dif
from fuel f inner join fuel ff
on ff.vehicle_no = f.vehicle_no and ff.date_issued < f.date_issued
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=62e1af4056f5e785105a0530d87c5258).
Results:

```
> id | id | vehicle_no | date_issued         | date_issued         | dif
> -: | -: | ---------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | --:
>  2 |  1 |        366 | 2019-09-02 00:00:00 | 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | 520
>  4 |  1 |        366 | 2019-09-04 00:00:00 | 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | 950
>  4 |  2 |        366 | 2019-09-04 00:00:00 | 2019-09-02 00:00:00 | 430
```